# iOS Google Maps API - Views do not Overlay Over the Map in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-maps

I want to add another view below the Map but the view disappear at run time.

at run time typeView disappears because of googlemap

[image]

edit

[image: at run time]

[image]

[image: type view]

Comment: Could you please provide some more clarity on the issue you are facing.

Comment: in run time typeView disappear because of googlemap

Comment: Okay, see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/43996292/5237727

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you asked, I understand that you want Type view to be shown over the Google Map. If so, then

1. Simply create an IBOutlet of the Type view as:

   ```
   @IBOutlet weak var typeView: UIView!
   ```
2. Use the below code to bring the typeView on the front:

   ```
   self.bringSubview(toFront: self.typeView)
   ```

(I am assuming that this code is to go in View)

Comment: @Amal El-galant: Also accept my answer if it helped you. Thanks!

Comment: thanks a lot typeView now appear but buttons inside it still hidden

Comment: @AmalEl-galant it might be autolayout issue.

Comment: i tried to uncheck autolayout but still the same problem can you help?

Comment: @AmalEl-galant Could you update your question with another screenshot showing the appearance of the view in interface builder? So that it gets easy to guide you with Autolayout.

Comment: @Amal El-galant
It can be seen that the constraints are conflicting for sure.
Clear the constraints for send and receive image and I am assuming that constraints for only these 2 buttons are conflicting.
Add these constraints:
1. For send image 
- leading space to super view
- top space to super view
- height fixed 
- width fixed

2. For receive image
- trailing space to super view
- top space to super view
- height fixed
- width fixed

Comment: actually the same constrains i added fixed hight and width only and those was the problem thanks alot

Answer (score 3):

Create storyboard connection the views,

```
@IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!
@IBOutlet weak var typeView: UIView!
```

Now, you can solve the issue by two ways,

**One way:**

```
self.mapView.sendSubview(toBack: self.typeView)
```

**The Second Way:**

```
self.view.bringSubview(toFront: self.typeView)
```

Comment: thank you second way helped me  typeView now appear but buttons inside it still hidden

Comment: @AmalEl-galant please can you give your code snippet?

Comment: override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            self.mapView = GMSMapView(frame: self.googlwMapViwe.frame)
            self.view.addSubview(self.mapView)
        
            self.view.bringSubviewToFront(TypeView) 
    }

Comment: @AmalEl-galant, remove self.view.addSubview(self.mapView) this line. This is unnecessary. And please try again.

Comment: @AmalEl-galant, Please take a look at here, https://github.com/GolapHasan/Google-Map-Demo